# List issues only showing the ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

My `issue.model.js` file looks like this:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
const IssueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  github_id: {
    type: String,
    description: 'The GitHub id of the issue'
  },
  issue_title: {
    type: String,
    description: 'The title of the issue'
  },
  issue_number: {
    type: String,
    description: 'The GitHub or Stackoverflow issue number'
  },
  issue_url: {
    type: String,
    description: 'The GitHub or Stackoverflow URL'
  },
  issue_state: {
    type: String,
    description: 'The current status of the issue on GitHub or Stackoverflow'
  }
})

export default mongoose.model('Issue', IssueSchema)
```

I have this route setup in `issue.routes.js`:

```
router.route('/api/issues')
  .get(authCtrl.requireSignin, issueCtrl.list)
```

My `issue.controller.js` is this:

```
import Issue from '../models/issue.model'
import _ from 'lodash'
import errorHandler from './../helpers/dbErrorHandler'


const list = (req, res) => {
  Issue.find((err, issues) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      })
    }
    res.json(issues)
  }).select('Something not right')
}

export default {
  list
}
```

When I do a `GET` at endpoint `localhost:3000/api/issues` I expect to see something like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c024d774bf16a46c4cf4155"),
    "github_id" : "123456789",
    "issue_title" : "test issue 2",
    "issue_number" : "2",
    "issue_url" : "https://api.github.com/repos/Org/test/issues/2",
    "issue_state" : "open",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Instead I get this:

```
{
    "_id": "5c024d774bf16a46c4cf4155"
}
```

I'm using Insomnia to check this. the route seems to be OK as I'm at least getting the correct ID's. I've compared the controller and model to a similar example and can't see what I'm missing. Can anybody show me where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Issue.find((err, issues) => {`
to

```
Issue.find({}, 'github_id issue_title issue_number issue_url issue_state',(err, issues) => {
```

This way you can include more fields.
See examples in docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Comment: Perfect thanks. I had tried `Issue.find({}, (err, issues) => {` with no joy. Didn't know about adding the keys.